# Multiplication Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication

I have one matrix `a` with 24 rows and 44 columns and another one `b` with 44 rows and one column. I would like to multiply the first row of matrix `b` with the entire column of matrix `a`, and the second row of matrix `b` with the entire column of matrix `a` and so forth. How can I do that?

Comment: Try `m1*m2[col(m1)]`

Comment: May someone explain to me why i took two negative votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can replicate the elements in the second matrix ('m2') to make the lengths same as in 'm1' and then do the multiplication.

```
m1*m2[col(m1)]
```

---

For replicating the elements, we used `col`, which returns the numeric index of the columns of the matrix ('m1')

```
 col(m1)
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 #[1,]    1    2    3    4
 #[2,]    1    2    3    4
 #[3,]    1    2    3    4
 #[4,]    1    2    3    4
 #[5,]    1    2    3    4
```

By doing `m2[col(m1)]`, the first element in 'm2' i.e. row1 column1 element is replicated 5 times, second 5 times, and so on.

```
 m2[col(m1)]
 #[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(1:20, ncol=4)
m2 <- matrix(1:4, nrow=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

This alternative uses vector recycling:

```
t(t(m1) * as.vector(m2))
```

Since the vector is recycled in the same way a matrix is filled (by columns), we need to first transpose `m1` and then transpose the result again.